# Render correct action within parent controller when using inheritance hierarchy - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, controller, sti

I am working with a code base that has this single table inheritance hierarchy:

BlogEntryWizardController < BlogEntriesController < CommonEntryController < ApplicationController

BlogEntryWizardController (BEWC) uses the same model that BlogEntriesController (BEC) uses.  The only real difference between the BEWC and the BEC is the views (one is just a tutorial wizard of the other).  Upon submitting the form within the wizard, it keeps taking the user to the "show" action of the BEC, the parent.  This occurs within CommonEntryController (CEC):

```
format.html {
  render(:action => 'show')
}
```

This invokes the show method of the BEC, but I need it to invoke the overriden show method within the BEWC.  Is there a way of distinguishing within CE which "show" action to call appropriately?

Thanks for your two cents.

Comment: Does the form submit to an action in the BEWC or the BEC?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, STI does not call for controller inheritance.

Comment: I suppose it's not necessary, but the information in this question is too vague for anybody to help regardless.  BEWC and BEC use the same model? Is it also the same model the CEC uses? What controller/action is this form posting to? Why did he post the CEC action in his question if he's trying to render a BEC/BEWC action? The background is very unclear.

Comment: @Brett Bender, The form is supposed to submit and then display then render the show action within the BEWC.  It submits correctly, but takes the user to the show action within the BEC.

Comment: @Brett Bender, Yes, BEWC and BEC use the same model. When the user submits a blog entry, it submits and saves the blog entry accordingly. The same thing happens when the user submits a blog entry via the wizard. The wizard will guide them through how to create a blog entry, but it still gets submitted correctly.  The form is posting to the BEC controller which invokes a method within CEC, which then renders to the show action.  Hence, the code snippet is within CEC.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way within CEC, if I can say, "If from the wizard, render the wizard's action."

Comment: In other words, when the code execution lies in the parent controller, is there a way to dictate, "If I arrived here from the child controller A, run the action within child controller A, otherwise, run the action in child controller B" based off of the hierarchy I posted above?

Comment: When rendering the action to "show", Rails is smart enough to realize what controller you want the action to be called on, as it probably analyzes which controller it's getting a @blogentry from.  So this is pretty much me answering my own question.  Anyone feel free to expand on this comment or any previous comments.  Thanks for everyone's notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the "show" action within BEC, send the redirect to the show controller:

```
redirect_to :controller => "BEWC", :action => "show"
```

Doing just that isn't enough as instance variables aren't persistent between controllers.  So you can save your BEC instance variable within a session and retrieve it within your BEWC contoller in your "show" action.